# What is the best memory management for GCC C++?

Tags: c++

What's the problem of my memory management? Because it causes crash that I show in a comment in the code below ("A memory block could not be found when trying to free."). I know that my memory management is not thread safe because I use global variables `g_numBlocks` and `g_blocks` that can cause risk when using multiple threads.

Since my memory management code seems too complex, can anyone suggest a stable and better "Memory Management for C++" to avoid memory leaks.

**The code that contains bug**

```
#include "emc-memory.h" // <-- Declare the functions MALLOC() and FREE() from other library.
#include <vector>

int main() {
    printf("HERE(1)\n");
    {
        std::vector<string> paths = { // <-- Problem, 'std::vector' & 'string' use internal malloc/free & operator new/delete that are overwritten with my own custom memory management.
            "/foo/bar.txt",
            "/foo/bar.",
            "/foo/bar",
            "/foo/bar.txt/bar.cc",
            "/foo/bar.txt/bar.",
            "/foo/bar.txt/bar",
            "/foo/.",
            "/foo/..",
            "/foo/.hidden",
            "/foo/..bar",
        };
    } // <-- It crashes here, error in FREE(): "A memory block could not be found when trying to free.".
    printf("HERE(2)\n"); // The reason I know it crashes above is this line is not evaluated, only "HERE(1)" is printed. I'm using [RelWithDebInfo] with blurry debugging info.
    return 0;
}
```

**Compilers:**

- [Visual Studio 2015] [Debug]: No problem.
- [Visual Studio 2015] [RelWithDebInfo]: No problem.
- [GCC 12.1.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32] [Debug]: No problem.
- [GCC 12.1.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32] [RelWithDebInfo]: **Broken which means there's a bug.**

---

**In "emc-memory.h" in other library .so file**

```
extern const char*  __file;
extern int          __line;
#define new (__file = __FILE__, __line = __LINE__, 0) ? 0 : new
enum MEMORYBLOCKTYPE {
    MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_MALLOC,
    MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_NEW,
};
void *MALLOC(size_t size, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE type);
void *REALLOC(void *block, size_t newSize);
void  FREE(void *block, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE type);
#define malloc(size)            ((__file = __FILE__, __line = __LINE__, 0) ? 0 : MALLOC(size, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_MALLOC))
#define realloc(block, newSize) REALLOC(block, newSize)
#define free(block)             FREE(block, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_MALLOC)
```

**In "emc-memory.cpp" in other library .so file**

I use this code in a link to override the operator new & delete: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/custom-operator-new-and-operator-delete

```
typedef unsigned long long BlockId; // The reason it's 64-bit is a memory block can be freed and reallocated multiple times, which means that there can be a lot of ids.
BlockId g_blockId = 0;
BlockId newBlockId() {
    return g_blockId++;
}

struct Block {
    const char          *file;
    int                  line;
    const char          *scope;
    char                *hint;
    size_t               size;
    BlockId              id; // That id is used for comparison because it will never be changed but the block pointer can be changed.
    void                *block;
    MEMORYBLOCKTYPE      type;
};

bool g_blocks_initialized = false;
int g_numBlocks;
Block **g_blocks;

void *MALLOC(size_t size, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE type) {
    if (g_blocks_initialized == false) {
        g_blocks_initialized = true;
        _initializeList(g_numBlocks, g_blocks);
    }
    Block *b = (Block *)malloc(sizeof(*b));
    b->file  = __file ; __file  = nullptr;
    b->line  = __line ; __line  = 0;
    b->scope = __scope; __scope = nullptr;
    b->hint  = allocateMemoryHint(__hint);
    b->size = size;
    b->id = newBlockId();
    b->block = malloc(size);
    b->type = type;
    _addListItem(g_numBlocks, g_blocks, b);
    return b->block;
}

void FREE(void *block, MEMORYBLOCKTYPE type) {
    if (block == nullptr) {
        return; // 'free' can free a nullptr.
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < g_numBlocks; i++) {
        Block *b = g_blocks[i];
        if (b->block == block) {
            if (b->type != type) {
                switch (type) {
                case MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_MALLOC: EMC_ERROR("The memory block type must be MALLOC."); break;
                case MEMORYBLOCKTYPE_NEW:    EMC_ERROR("The memory block type must be NEW.");    break;
                default:                     EMC_ERROR("Error");                                 break;
                }
            }
            _removeListItem(g_numBlocks, g_blocks, b);
            freeMemoryHint(b->hint); b->hint = nullptr;
            SAFE_FREE(b->block);
            SAFE_FREE(b);
            return;
        }
    }
    EMC_ERROR("A memory block could not be found when trying to free.\n\nExamples:\n - Calling free(pointer) where pointer was not set to zero after it's been called twice, the solution was to use SAFE_FREE(). And if possible, replace any free() with SAFE_FREE(). For example, see Lexer::read0() on the original line \"free(out.asIdentifier);\".\n - If an 'Engine' object is destroyed before destroying a Vulkan object then it can cause this error (It can happen with 'Release' or 'RelWithDebInfo' configuration but not with 'Debug' configuration), that problem happened to me and I stuck there for hours until I realized it.");
}
```

Comment: why are you doing any of this in the first place?

Comment: If you use the malloc/free that came with GCC, does it crash?  Or does it only crash with emc-memory?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question seems too difficult. I'm building a big serious project and I want to avoid memory leaks, sometimes there's an explosion of memory, for example it keeps increasing very fast in a second and the only solution to detect such problem is using "Memory Management" by looking to all the allocated memories in any time and it solved my memory leak problem. But I'm stuck when I move to GCC.

Comment: You don't like having to manage the memory yourself? Then why are you using C or C++? Use C# or Java, as they do it for you.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to write big professional applications in modern C++ with good performance and no memory leaks, *without* ever resorting to manual memory management. In fact, with modern C++ I tend to view any use of manual memory management as a huge red flag indicating that the author is likely either a beginner, incompetent or not up-to-date on modern C++.

Comment: "_...avoid memory leaks, ..."_ use containers; use smart pointers (treat `std::shared_ptr` as a potential red-flag in design review); never use new / malloc.

Comment: Eljay > I tried to comment `#include "emc-memory.h"` and insert `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string>` and there's still a crash, so I conclude that the separated libraries that contain "emc-memory.cpp" is still linked to the current cpp project even if I don't include "emc-memory.h". I will come back later, I don't know if I need to check if it's the same with Visual Studio.

Comment: string here `std::vector<string>` is std::string or your own class?

Comment: KoVadim > std::vector is not my own class, it's the official vector, and std::string too is the official string. I realize that even if I comment "emc-memory.h" on Visual Studio or GCC, then all malloc/free/new/delete are overwritten with my own memory management. So I conclude that my memory management is not supported by GCC but supported with Visual Studio, it contains bug but I don't know where.

People suggest `std::shared_ptr` but how to manage all the memories, how to know the total amount of allocated of memory with it? But I don't know where is the problem in my code?

Comment: This is probably calling gcc's builtin malloc (via operator new) and not yours, because you didn't redefine operator new

Comment: Btw; since you are using `malloc` and `free` rather than `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]`, I hope you don't use this to allocate and release any C++ objects (except PODs), since constructors/destructors won't be called and your code will break left and right.

Comment: @mandaxyz - it looks like string is not a std::string. just add std:: on the begin `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: For the benefit of those who haven't understood. The OP has overridden the global new and delete operators with their own code. It's normal to do that as some level of wrapper on `malloc()` an `free()` which are guaranteed to never call `new` or `delete`. Please note I aam not vindicating any of this! I'm just trying to clear up some of the confusions above. If the OP's code uses `shared_ptr` they will still get the same problem because they have directed shared_ptr through their homespun thread-unsafe `new` and `delete` operators.

Comment: "What is the best memory management for GCC C++?" - The *best* memory management is that which happens automatically. The *worst* memory management is the manual kind. And what compiler you use is not at all relevant..

Comment: I believe the GCC allocator still owes some inheritance to Doug Lea's `malloc()` from the early 1990s and is very much 'field tested and hardened' (for 30 years over many trillions of uses) to be a stalwart general purpose implementation that is yet to be bettered outside specific applications with unusual use patterns.

Comment: As far as I understood from his/her comment the OP wants to log/display the current memory allocations to find memory leaks, not improve their performance ("*and the only solution to detect such problem is using "Memory Management" by looking to all the allocated memories in any time and it solved my memory leak problem*"), which is a valid use case. (Yes, memory leaks can be avoided with smart pointers and RIIA, and their exist solutions for logging allocations or testing for leaks).

Comment: Redefining language keywords (e.g. `#define new <something>`) the way you are gives undefined behaviour.  Also, `std::vector` and `std::string` both use allocators (specialisations of a templated `std::allocate`) to manage dynamically allocated memory rather than using `new` and `delete` expressions directly, so their interactions with your `new` macro is not necessarily what you expect.

Comment: Why don't you just use an address sanitizer? All those macros are of no use. :/ Memory allocation can happen in libraries built without those macros. Your best bet is to use the ASAN, not trying to reinvent the wheel. But if you have to, `new` and `delete` should be overriden by implementing global functions called `operator new` and `operator delete`. `malloc` and `free` would require some non-portable hack.

Answer (score 3):

I would humbly suggest that without a very clear reason to think otherwise the best memory management for GCC C++ is the out-of-the-box default memory management for GCC C++.

That would mean your best solution would have been to do nothing or as it is now strip out your overrides of the global operators.

You may find in some area of a system the default memory management is sub-optimal but in 2022 the default options are very effective and if you find a general purpose strategy that is better it's a publishable paper.

However your question tells us nothing about the application in question or your motivations for thinking you should even try to change the memory management let alone give advice on what to.

Sure you can add a global allocation mutex to block memory management and make it thread-safe. I will be surprised if that doesn't turn out to more than throw away whatever advantage you're hoping to gain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where SAFE_FREE is coming from.
If you see in MALLOC function, they use c runtime malloc. Meaning that if you want to free the block you need to use the corresponding free() function.

Make sure that SAFE_FREE is indeed using the c runtime free with the correct parameters.

Comment: ```#ifndef SAFE_FREE
#define SAFE_FREE(p)            { if (p) { free (p);       (p)=nullptr; } } ((void)0) // There must be ";".
#endif```
They came from DirectX.
I'm asking how people could manage big memory, if I can fix the bug in my code, then it's great but it seems difficult. One thing is sure, it's better to always use `std::shared_ptr` to avoid memory leak. But I want to manage the memory anyway by looking at all the memory blocks.

Comment: @mandaxyz "`if (p) { free (p);`" is nonsense. If `p` is `nullptr` then `free(p);` is a no-op. You don't need to check for that.

Comment: @mandaxyz `((void)0) // There must be ";". #endif` - Ehh... The usual way to ensure a terminating `;` in a macro is `do { /* stuff */ } while (false)`, but the *better* way is to *NOT* use macros in the first place and just use a proper function.

Comment: but if SAFE_FREE is using free() and free() is re-defined as FREE isnt it recursive? @mandaxyz

Comment: Also, not sure what is the point of managing the memory but since you are using mingw, I guess the platform is windows. Have a look at the winapi function VirtualQuery. See if you can get what you need without having to build a wrapper around malloc and free.